# Is it possible to request data from Neo4j database without authentication?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Javascript Bolt Driver on Google Cloud Functions to query Neo4j database and then send the result to the client, is it possible to access the database without authentication?, does the authentication slow down the query time between Client and Server?.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable authentication/authorization in [neo4j.conf](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/enable/) file:

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

However it is strongly recommended to leave it on as it makes whole database accessible to anyone with access to the host and port (bolt or http). Even in environments where you can limit the access to the machine to particular network or range of IPs it is better to keep the authentication on as additional layer of protection.

The performance impact is negligible compared to all other variables usually involved (network, disk access, query planning and execution).

Comment: I read the manual, can a user set his own user and password to access database and restrict him by assigning a role ?

Comment: Roles are supported in enterprise edition only. https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/native-roles/